# Question about computer engineering circuits (noob question)

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, short-circuit, computer-architecture

I'm currently self learning computer engineering stuff right now and I was wondering how RAM would work in terms of input and output and I stumbled upon this image

[image]

I think it's somewhat wrong from what I know so far. The data bus is used for reading and writing. Wouldn't that cause a short circuit? It means that there are logic gates facing outwards from the RAM towards the databus and if the CPU were to send a certain byte, the current would flow towards the output of the logic gate?

I'm not so sure if I'm right, but I did use *digital* which is a logic circuit simulator, and whenever I connect a button to an output such as this one

[image]

It would cause a short circuit apparently. I researched a bit about that and I learned that short circuits occur whenever there's a mix of  a hot wire and a neutral wire, which I believe in computing corresponds to two output circuits with 1 and 0 on the same wire.

Comment: Nope, not right. Data buses are both inputs and outputs, just not simultaneously. It will be an output only when you want to read from memory. Otherwise it is an input which allows you to write to memory.

Comment: To get a good understanding of how computer electronics work, you may want to start with the theory behind them. I’ve found this book is pretty inclusive to start off assuming you know the basics of electricity. https://www.amazon.com/Microelectronic-Circuits-Electrical-Computer-Engineering/dp/0199339139

Comment: A good book for beginners is Charles Petzold Code The Hidden Language Of Computer Hardware And Software https://archive.org/details/CharlesPetzoldCodeTheHiddenLanguageOfComputerHardwareAndSoftwareMicrosoftPress2000

Comment: Daniel, If can manage it get the book called *"Bebop BYTES back: An Unconventional Guide to Computers"* by Clive Maxfield. It's excellent at your level, I think. [Don Lancaster's list of his books you can get for free](https://www.tinaja.com/ebksamp1.shtml) doesn't include it, but years before Clive's book, Don wrote a two volume set called the "Micro Cookbook" that is also good to get, though today a bit dated. It's just that it was well-written for your level, as well.

Comment: Daniel, Your first image is of a 256x8. That's nice. Here's what I had to use: [Intel 8101 256x4 on page 5-67](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/intel/MCS80/98-153B_Intel_8080_Microcomputer_Systems_Users_Manual_197509.pdf). You can see one [on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/p/1256669675). Pricey. Had to use two of them to get to 256x8! But you will notice that the data in and data out were separate, then, too. More like you were expecting, I think. (So not all similar things are done the same way.)

Answer (score 4):

> The data bus is used for reading and writing.

Correct.

> Wouldn't that cause a short circuit?

No. The circuits are are arranged so that only one device is asserting a signal onto the data lines at any instant. The others are all just "watching" the data lines and can read the logic level.

> ... the electricity would move towards the output of the logic gate?

We would say, "current will flow from the logic high device to the logic low device".

> ... it would cause a short circuit apparently, ...

Short-circuit usually means that the current is taking a short-cut around the intended circuit. What you are describing is just a high current flow due to a conflict between two output devices - one trying to connect the line to V+ and the other to ground.

> I researched a bit about that and i learned that short circuit occurs whenever there's a mix of a hot wire and a neutral wire ...

Live and neutral are terms used in mains AC wiring. Use "logic high" and "logic low" for digital circuits.

Comment: I would modify this to grant that, if the system is not designed right, it IS possible for two outputs to drive the same line. It's called bus contention and can be a problem. But normally no two devices try to drive the bus at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Memory chips (and many other parts that are used to drive a bus) have an "Output Enable" input.  Their output driver circuits are only active when that input is in its Active state-  otherwise, the data bus pins are inputs.

Normally, only one part connected to the data bus will have its Output Enable active.

Answer (score 0):

The data pins on a RAM chip need to be "tristate".  A tristate pin can be output high, output low, or high impedance (input only).

Each RAM chip will need a number of state pins telling it what to do.  This will vary between memories, but there will some kind of "chip select" to tell the RAM chip when you are talking to it, rather than anything else, and a "read/write" pin to tell it whether you want to set the memory or read it.

When the chip is not selected, or if it's being written to, then all the data pins will be high impedance.  When the chip is being read, the pins will be high or low as required.